# Issue with PHP file upload

Tags: php

PHP is a language that I know very little of, and today I've been given a task part of which involves uploading a file with PHP because, I think, the easiest way to make an unimportant interface is making it with HTML. I wrote some code but when I open it on my browser - even before I hit submit - an error message appears, saying:

> Notice: Undefined index: resume in C:\wamp\www\cv_base\index.php on line 39

The code is following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>::Welcome to Resume Base::</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/engine.js"></script>
    </head><body>
        <div id="container">
            <h1>Add A Resume</h1>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="id_firstname" maxlength="20" placeholder="First Name" required="required" />
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="id_lasttname" maxlength="20" placeholder="Last Name" required="required" />
                <input type="text" name="paternal" id="id_paternal" maxlength="20" placeholder="Paternal Name" required="required" />
                <select name="category">
                    <option selected disabled>Choose Category...</option>
                    <option value="IT & Computers">IT & Computers</option>
                    <option value="Design">Design</option>
                    <option value="Services">Services</option>
                    <option value="Agriculture & Industry">Agriculture & Industry</option>
                    <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
                    <option value="Marketing & Sales">Marketing & Sales</option>
                    <option value="Administrative">Administrative</option>
                    <option value="Medical">Medical</option>
                    <option value="Science & Education">Science & Education</option>
                    <option value="Law">Law</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
                <input type="file" name="resume" id="id_resume" required="required" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="id_submit" value="Apply!" />
            </form>
            [<a href="search.php">Search</a>]
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
require_once "connection.php";

$targetDir = "resumes/";
$targetFile = $targetDir . basename($_FILES["resume"]["name"]);
$uploadFinish = 1;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $fname = $_POST["firstname"];
    $lname = $_POST["lastname"];
    $pname = $_POST["paternal"];
    $cat = $_POST["category"];
    if ($fileType != "doc" && $fileType != "docx" && $fileType != "odt" && $fileType != "pdf") {
        echo "Invalid file format!";
        $uploadFinish = 0;
    } elseif ($_FILES["resume"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "File too large! Choose another file.";
        $uploadFinish = 0;
    } elseif (file_exists ($targetFile)) {
        echo "File already exists! Choose another file or rename file.";
        $uploadFinish = 0;
    } else {
        $uploadFinish = 1;
    }

    if ($uploadFinish == 0) {
        echo "File not uploaded!";
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"], $targetFile)) {
            echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["resume"]["name"]) . " uploaded.";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO applicants VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->execute(array($fname, $lname, $pname, $cat, $targetFile));
        } else {
            echo "Error uploading file!";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I have taken the lines 38-41 and 64-65 from the Internet, but they seem to be the part where the problem occurs. Please, help!

UPDATE: Thanks, mates! I finally finished the project thanks to you!

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: your accessing the $_FILES array regardless of if there is a file in it. you can move it inside of your condition. As long as resume is a required field you shouldn't get that error after that

Comment: @matthewdaniel Did it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script assumes that `$_FILES['resume']` exists, but it will only exist if the form has been properly submitted.

These four lines:

```
$targetDir = "resumes/";
$targetFile = $targetDir . basename($_FILES["resume"]["name"]);
$uploadFinish = 1;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Need to move into the `if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {` conditional with everything else that depends on the form being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

"undefined index" indicates you're attempting to access a part of a hashmap that doesn't exist. Line 39 is this:

```
$targetFile = $targetDir . basename($_FILES["resume"]["name"]);
```

Here you're accessing the `$_FILES` variable and trying to get the "resume" index of that hashmap. That index does not exist, thereby causing your error.

Answer (score -2):

There's a few issues.

First of all, you are running the PHP code when the user is just loading the page. You should wrap the logic to handle the upload in something like this.

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Your form will need the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to handle files.

It's clearly poorly organized code. This is a one off so you probably don't care, but if you find yourself writing PHP more frequently, consider using functions, frameworks, and other concepts to make your projects much easier.

Finally, there's huge security holes. Make sure the form isn't available to the internet or you may have more serious issues on your hands.

Comment: Thanks a lot! (+1)

Comment: While you are pointing out important things about the code, the error that is stopping the OP is clearly stated, and doesn't have anything to do with the logic wrap, or the SQL injection attack they are super-open to. To be clear: this is good information, but belongs in a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: @NathanielFord The logic wrap prevents the code from working. Because the code runs on page load, the index will always be empty. Both our answers point out issues stopping the code. Also, it's not a SQL injection attack, there's no database interaction in his code, it's file, filename, etc attacks. Finally, pointing out security issues is common and encouraged. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345664/should-the-answer-be-the-simplest-ever-possible-even-at-the-expense-of-quality/345665#345665

Comment: I'm not discouraging you from pointing out the security issue (though `$stmt->execute()` does execute against a db, in this case with user-supplied, unsanitized data), but the appropriate place for info that is appropriate but not relevant to the core question is in the comments section. To put it another way: if the OP fixed everything you cite, she or he could still have the issue, and would definitely not understand what the underlying problem was: that she or he is indexing to an index that does not exist.

Comment: Ah didn't notice the execute. Either way, both the indexing and the logic wrap were both underlying issues that were stopping code.